# How can I remove the trace of window movements when I move a form in windows xp?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a borderless form with a panel on top of it that I use to move and drag the form.  This does okay in windows 7, but I found that it shows window trails (like Mouse Trails, shadows/copy/traces of form) that moves along with it whenever I move the form.  I tried setting the Visual Effects to "Adjust for best appearance" thinking that it would fix this but to no avail.  Hope anyone could show me the light.. thanks

**additional info:** The display of the computer runs on Intel GMA 3100 and runs okay with other softwares.  I suspect that there's some setting that causes this and I'm pretty sure it is not because of the graphics card.  Thanks !

**CLUE?** I also tried finding the setting "Enable/Disable Desktop Composition" in WindowsXP to find a clue, but it seems that it is available only in Vista and 7, not in XP.  Because I think this is the culprit in XP that causes trails.  If this setting is disabled in Windows 7, my forms behave the same way as the XP's.  To put it back, I would have to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried finding the setting "Enable/Disable Desktop Composition" in WindowsXP

Windows XP is the root of the problem.  The issue is not located in your code, it is caused by the code in the program that owns the window that you overlap.  When you move your window, that program has to render the pixels that you revealed.  If it is slow to do so then you see the unpainted pixels for a while, visible as a white trail.  The length of the trail is determined by how fast you move your window and how slow that program responds.  Your video adapter doesn't help much either, it is about as slow as you can get.

A fundamental fix became available in Vista with the Aero desktop theme.  Which no longer lets a program render to the screen directly, output goes to a memory bitmap.  The screen view is then composited from those bitmaps.  With the significant advantage that those pixels you reveal by moving the window are instantly available and the overlapped window doesn't need to be repainted at all.  That feature is called "Desktop Composition".  Enabled by default on Windows 7.

Nothing you can do about this, other than retiring that old puppy.

Comment: Can the "Double Buffer" feature help in some way? I am sad about everything you said, that only means I have to let it that way.